# Bottom navigation bar not working properly

Tags: java, android, xml, bottomnavigationview

I have a bottom navigation bar in my app helps moving between activities (not fragments) but when I go back using the phones back button it works but the item in the nav bar doesn't change, I hope someone can help me with this

I tried to do it with the onBackPressed and getItem but getItem wasn't working, keeps asking me to rename it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.